# getting exception in below stacktrace program

Tags: java, multithreading

I have developed the program to prove that if thread and it is in static synchronized method still a thread  can enter other static synchronized method from that method in java itself but my programs throws the exception please advise what went wrong in it , below is the code

```
package com.synchrnozie;

class MyRunnable18 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        method1();
    }

    static synchronized void method1() {
        System.out.println("static synchronized void method1() started");
        method2();
        System.out.println("static synchronized void method1() ended");
    }

    static synchronized void method2() {
        System.out.println("in static synchronized method2()");
        method3();
    }

    static synchronized void method3() {
        System.out.println("in static synchronized method3()");
        method3();
    }

}

public class staticNesting {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        MyRunnable18 MyRunnable18 = new MyRunnable18();
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(MyRunnable18, "Thread-1");
        thread1.start();
    }

}
```

and below is the exception stack trace ..

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.withResult(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
    at com.synchrnozie.MyRunnable18.method3(staticNesting.java:24)
    at com.synchrnozie.MyRunnable18.method3(staticNesting.java:25)
```

Comment: You are calling method3() from method3() repeatedly.So there is ending for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror

You can refer this

Answer (score 1):

Your methode3() call method3() infinitly  , maybe that's why ?

Answer (score 1):

You are making recursive calls to method3 which is resulting in stackoverlflow error.

```
 static synchronized void method3() {
            System.out.println("in static synchronized method3()");
            method3();
        }
```